# Change /add items in menu on the inner sidebar

Tags: sidebar

I have a home sidebar menu of items and I need to add an item (post) so it displays. There is no add button availalble. How do you add another post so it shows on the home inner sidebar menu list

Answer (score 0):

You have to create menu from the menu page in `Appearance->Menu` tab which you want in sidebar.
Then you can select this menu from sidebar custom menu widget from `Appearance->Widget` tab.